High Validation Accuracy + High Loss Score and High Training Accuracy + Low Loss Score?
I am having a wierd observation in my experiments, I am using BERT with adapter and lora PEFT methods for domain adaptation. I first trained the adapter on Unlabled target domain dataset using MLM, then further trains it with lora on labled source domain dataset. I do validation and testing on subsets from both domains to measure performance. I am also using pytorch lightning.
But i am noticing something unusual, I am noticing that both Accuracy, F1, and also Val loss increasing on validation sets, and at the same time training Accuracy also increases and its loss decreases.
How is that even happening, it should clearly indicates overfitting, but why accuracy and F1 score increases on val sets from both domains? even the metrics on test sets also perform well.
I want to know is this a problem or not, and how to solve it if so?
I saw [this][1]  , I kind of understand some rational behind why it happens, but no one explained if it is a problem or not, is it reliable?
I am noticing the same behaviour and same obeservation with different random seeds with different domains in MNLI dataset.
Below you can find one example of the results on Fiction domain to Slate domain:
target_val/loss: 1.0985016822814941
target_val/accuracy: 0.34375
target_val/f1: 0.21794871985912323
source_val/loss: 1.1062182188034058
source_val/accuracy: 0.3125
source_val/f1: 0.23592719435691833
========

target_val/loss: 0.699775218963623
target_val/accuracy: 0.7106826305389404
target_val/f1: 0.6965627074241638
source_val/loss: 0.6004047989845276
source_val/accuracy: 0.7540778517723083
source_val/f1: 0.7420787811279297
====
target_val/loss: 0.6732573509216309
target_val/accuracy: 0.7289378046989441
target_val/f1: 0.7175418734550476
source_val/loss: 0.5516898036003113
source_val/accuracy: 0.7798634767532349
source_val/f1: 0.7691917419433594
===
target_val/loss: 0.7151115536689758
target_val/accuracy: 0.7307456731796265
target_val/f1: 0.7188504934310913
source_val/loss: 0.5572002530097961
source_val/accuracy: 0.7889435291290283
source_val/f1: 0.7788199782371521
=====
target_val/loss: 0.7140771746635437
target_val/accuracy: 0.7409878969192505
target_val/f1: 0.7306339740753174
source_val/loss: 0.5693668127059937
source_val/accuracy: 0.7944554686546326
source_val/f1: 0.78414386510849
=====
target_val/loss: 0.7778016328811646
target_val/accuracy: 0.7373721599578857
target_val/f1: 0.726191520690918
source_val/loss: 0.6007576584815979
source_val/accuracy: 0.7945438027381897
source_val/f1: 0.7854850888252258
===
target_val/loss: 0.8652549982070923
target_val/accuracy: 0.7484367489814758
target_val/f1: 0.7384369969367981
source_val/loss: 0.6639459729194641
source_val/accuracy: 0.802937388420105
source_val/f1: 0.7942846417427063
======
target_val/loss: 0.9154067635536194
target_val/accuracy: 0.7489532828330994
target_val/f1: 0.7391778826713562
source_val/loss: 0.701705276966095
source_val/accuracy: 0.8042287230491638
source_val/f1: 0.7955416440963745
========
target_val/loss: 0.9541056752204895
target_val/accuracy: 0.7468871474266052
target_val/f1: 0.7366498708724976
source_val/loss: 0.726020097732544
source_val/accuracy: 0.8053908944129944
source_val/f1: 0.7968654036521912
=========
target_val/loss: 0.944335401058197
target_val/accuracy: 0.7510194182395935
target_val/f1: 0.7405691742897034
source_val/loss: 0.7197132110595703
source_val/accuracy: 0.8059074282646179
source_val/f1: 0.7975500226020813
=====
target_val/loss: 0.9441717267036438
target_val/accuracy: 0.751535952091217
target_val/f1: 0.7413626909255981
source_val/loss: 0.7214362621307373
source_val/accuracy: 0.8051326274871826
source_val/f1: 0.796737790107727
`Trainer.fit` stopped: `max_epochs=10` reached.
Some weights of BertAdapterModel were not initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-uncased and are newly initialized: ['heads.default.3.bias']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
================================================================================
Name                     Architecture         #Param      %Param  Active   Train
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
task_FS_invLora_stack_f1 lora                294,912       0.269       1       1
mlm_inv_S                bottleneck        7,387,776       6.748       1       1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Full model                               109,482,240     100.000               0
================================================================================
LOCAL_RANK: 0 - CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: [0]

Testing DataLoader 0: 100%
 62/62 [00:11<00:00,  5.32it/s]
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃        Test metric        ┃       DataLoader 0        ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│   source_test/accuracy    │    0.7901545763015747     │
│      source_test/f1       │    0.7802497148513794     │
│     source_test/loss      │    0.7863523364067078     │
│   target_test/accuracy    │    0.7550402879714966     │
│      target_test/f1       │    0.7448281645774841     │
│     target_test/loss      │    0.9789300560951233     │
└───────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
 

Note that the accuracy and F1 scores on training data is very high (some times it reaches to 1) and train loss is low, this is cleearly overfitting, but how is it giving high testing results (The testing results are suffecient for me BTW)?
Should i rely on that despite the wierd behaviour and report the results as final results? or should i fix it more? How could i fix it if it needs to?
Again this behaviour is continously repeating with different random seeds and with different domains.
